# Ansible Jinja2 template - Remove trailing whitespace

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-vault

I am trying to load an ansible vault file into an k8 configmap YAML file using Ansible Jinja template but facing an issue with a trailing whitespace getting added at the end of the contents of the YAML file. This is causing errors as below:

`Vault format unhexlify error: Odd-length string`

Sample of ansible template am using is :

## Playbook main.yml -

> ```
> - name: display multiple files   
>   shell: cat /tmp/test.yml   
>   register: test
> ```

## Ansible Jinja Template

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> data:
>  test.yml: |-
>      {{ test.stdout.splitlines()|indent(4, false)|trim|replace(' ','') }}
> kind: ConfigMap
> metadata: 
>   name: test
>   namespace: test-namespace
> ```

## test.yml example:

> ```
>   $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
>   62313365396662343061393464336163383764373764613633653634306231386433626436623361
>   6134333665353966363534333632666535333761666131620a663537646436643839616531643561
>   63396265333966386166373632626539326166353965363262633030333630313338646335303630
>   3438626666666137650a353638643435666633633964366338633066623234616432373231333331
>   6564
> ```

## Output YAML created from Jinja Template is below

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> data:
>  test.yml:
>      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
>   62313365396662343061393464336163383764373764613633653634306231386433626436623361
>   6134333665353966363534333632666535333761666131620a663537646436643839616531643561
>   63396265333966386166373632626539326166353965363262633030333630313338646335303630
>   3438626666666137650a353638643435666633633964366338633066623234616432373231333331
>   6564   
> kind: ConfigMap
> metadata: 
>   name: test
>   namespace: test-namespace
> ```

Can you please let me know what i may be missing in my ansible template file to fix the above trailing whitespace issues.

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Just post the text itself in your question, properly formatted.

Comment: Please explain what the **problem** is; you have what appears to be a jinja2 template that is generating yaml text, but I don't see what ansible-vault has to do with any of that

Comment: I have edited my question without any pictures and also provided more details on the questions. I am trying to load a Ansible Vault encrypted file into a configmap using jinja2 templating. When doing the same the output ConfigMap has a space added in the end of the encrypted file which is causing corruption of the same and giving me the above ansible vault error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to load a Ansible Vault encrypted file into a configmap using jinja2 templating

Then you are solving the wrong problem; let the `to_yaml` filter do all that escaping for you, rather than trying to jinja your way through it.

```
- command: cat /tmp/test.yml
  register: tmp_test
- set_fact:
    cm_skeleton:
      apiVersion: v1
      data:
      kind: ConfigMap
      metadata: 
        name: test
        namespace: test-namespace
- copy:
    content: >-
      {{ cm_skeleton | combine({"data":{"test.yml": tmp_test.stdout}}) | to_yaml }}
    dest: /tmp/test.configmap.yml
```

If you have other things you are trying to template into that `ConfigMap`, fine, you can still do so, but deserialize in into a `dict` so you can insert the literal contents of `test.yml` into the `dict` and then re-serialize using the `to_yaml` filter:

```
- set_fact:
   cm_skeleton: '{{ lookup("template", "cm.j2") | from_yaml }}'
- copy:
   contents: '{{ cm_sketeton | combine({"data"...}) | to_yaml }}'
```